# PKEY_EdgeGesture_DisableTouchWhenFullscreen undeclared identifier

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, windows-8, mfc

This is with a vs2010 MFC Dialog Application. Besides the below code I've also tried including the following libs, ehstorguids.lib Uuid.Lib. The end result I'm aiming for is to kill the windows 8 Charms Bar. What am I missing to cause this undeclared identifier.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <propsys.h>
#include <propkey.h>

using namespace std;

HRESULT SetTouchDisableProperty(HWND hwnd, BOOL fDisableTouch)
{
    IPropertyStore* pPropStore;
    HRESULT hrReturnValue = SHGetPropertyStoreForWindow(hwnd, IID_PPV_ARGS(&pPropStore));
    if (SUCCEEDED(hrReturnValue))
    {
        PROPVARIANT var;
        var.vt = VT_BOOL;
        var.boolVal = fDisableTouch ? VARIANT_TRUE : VARIANT_FALSE;
        hrReturnValue = pPropStore->SetValue(PKEY_EdgeGesture_DisableTouchWhenFullscreen, var);
        pPropStore->Release();
    }
    return hrReturnValue;
}

BOOL CALLBACK MyEnumProc(HWND hWnd, LPARAM lParam)
{
    TCHAR title[500];
    ZeroMemory(title, sizeof(title));    

    GetWindowText(hWnd, title, sizeof(title)/sizeof(title[0]));

    if (!_tcscmp(title, _T("helloworld")))
    {
        SetTouchDisableProperty(hWnd,true);
    }

    return TRUE;
}

void mymfcdialog::ObBnClickedOk()
{   
    EnumWindows(MyEnumProc, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Windows 8 SDK is required for declaration even though VS was not complaining about the libs which are required per MSDN which where included.

This method of hiding/disabling Charms only works with desktop apps when they are full screen and have a title bar. So in my case, this would not working. Killing the 'explorer' process when no charms bar/gestures are desired and then relaunching the explorer process is the only option. If MS reads this, you really should look around, this should not be required to hide/disable Charms/Gestures. But then again, look at windows at Windows 8...I mean 8.1....Still haven't got it right.

Answer (score 0):

Your original code doesn't look wrong to me. In fact, there are working examples of this online.

The best I found was https://github.com/Kuqd/DisableCharmBar, which demonstrates a working example.

The limitation regarding the window title bar, which you mention in your own answer, might be related to your `GetWindowText` checks. The example from Kuqd works without having a title bar.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this in my code, i hope it can help you:

```
    static Guid DISABLE_TOUCH_SCREEN = new Guid("32CE38B2-2C9A-41B1-9BC5-B3784394AA44"), // PKEY_EdgeGesture_DisableTouchWhenFullscreen
                IID_PROPERTY_STORE = new Guid("886d8eeb-8cf2-4446-8d02-cdba1dbdcf99"); // PropertyStore
    static short VT_BOOL = 11;   
    private const int GC_ALLGESTURES = 0x00000001;

    public static void DisableEdgeGestures(IntPtr hwnd)
    {
        win32.IPropertyStore pPropStore = null;
        int hr = 0;
        hr = win32.SHGetPropertyStoreForWindow(hwnd, ref IID_PROPERTY_STORE, out pPropStore);
        if (hr == 0)
        {
            win32.PropertyKey propKey = new win32.PropertyKey();
            propKey.fmtid = DISABLE_TOUCH_SCREEN;
            propKey.pid = 2;
            win32.PropVariant var = new win32.PropVariant();
            var.vt = VT_BOOL;
            var.boolVal = true;
            pPropStore.SetValue(ref propKey, ref var);
            System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(pPropStore);
        }
    }
```